# App not showing up in Search Result in Android market

Tags: android, search, google-play

I have uploaded an application in Android market. But when I search for the app the app do not appear in the autocomplete box which appears below the search box.

For example, if I type "h" in the search box the autocomplete box will have the applications with "h". But in my case I need to type the complete name of the application.

Why is it so? Is there something that I am missing.

Comment: Are you sure the Android market does that. I only remember having to type in something then hit search. It doesn't dynamically update like the iPhone. I'm double checking now.

Comment: Well, I have Nexus one with 2.2 in it. I have cleared all the data from Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Running. Select Android Market and then click clear data. I am not sure whether android market gets the list dynamically or from cache. I will like to know how we can get provide the application detail page to anyone. I have tried with market://details?id=package name. But that do not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

For my phone, HTC Magic Android 1.6 it doesn't dynamically search the market as I type. You have to type something then hit enter/search and it will find it. Just like using Google.

It does however dynamically show my recent search entries. So if I start type "h" it will show my recent keywords I used to search starting with "h".

I don't know if this goes for newer versions of Android....

Comment: What you say is also true for my 2.1 based phone. I think it only autocompletes recent search strings.